# Getting Super's property value instead of actual object

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following:

```
Public Abstract class Entity
  protected int damagePoints = 0;

  public getDamagePoints() {
     return this.damagePoints;
  }

Public abstract class IA extends Entity

Public class Zombie extends IA implements Attacker {
    protected int damagePoints = 40;
}

Public class Engineer extends Entity implements DamageReceiver;

Public interface Attacker {
   public attack(Entity entity);
}

Public interface DamageReceiver {
   public receiveDamage(Attacker entity)
}
```

The Engineer class has this method overriden:

```
@Override
    public void receiveDamage(Attacker entity) {
        if (entity instanceof Zombie) {
            int damagePoints = ((Zombie) entity).getDamagePoints();
            this.setHealthPoints(this.getHealthPoints() - damagePoints);
        }
    }
```

Now I have an Engineer instantiated, and a Zombie.
When I do `Zombie.attack(engineer)`, and I put a breakpoint in `receiveDamage()` in Engineer class, I get that `damagePoints` is `0`.

Any clue of why this happens? Is this because I duplicated the property `damagePoints`? If so, how can I have a Zombie to have 40 of damage points without repeating the `this.damagePoints = 40` in all constructors?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You re-declared `damagePoints` in `Zombie`, hoping that `getDamagePoints()` in `Entity` would pick up the new value in `Zombie`, but as you've seen, it didn't.  In Java, polymorphism works with method calls, but not with variables.  The `damagePoints` variable in `Entity` is the variable in scope for the `getDamagePoints()` method, so `0` is returned, from `Entity`'s `damagePoints` variable.

To get `40` returned in `Zombie`, you don't need to re-declare another variable of the same name, *hiding* the `damagePoints` variable in `Entity`,  but you can override the `getDamagePoints()` method in `Zombie`.  You don't need a variable for that, much less a variable of the same name (unless you plan on having that quantity change during the game).  In `Zombie`:

```
@Override
public int getDamagePoints() {
   return 40;
}
```

You may even want your `getDamagePoints()` method to be `abstract` in `Entity`, forcing subclasses to implement the method.  This would mean that the variable `damagePoints` would be unnecessary in `Entity`.

```
public abstract int getDamagePoints();
```

Comment: Well its not the answer I was hoping, because I thought that inheritance was to avoid repeating the same code. It is sad, I think PHP works the way I expect (IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you call `getDamagePoints`, it's returning the abstract class `Entity`'s damagePoints value, not the class that has extended it. Fix this by making `Entity`'s getDamagePoints method abstract, and provide an implementation for every extended class.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Zombie has multiple constructors, all of which need to initialize damagePoints to avoid repeated code, including possibly repeating the method getDamagePoints.

The solution is to use "this" to tie constructors together. For example, if one constructor takes a superset of the parameters for each of the other constructors, do the actual work in it:

```
public Zombie(/* some subset of parameters */){
  this(/* full set of parameters with defaults filled in */);
}

public Zombie(/* full set of parameters */){
  damagePoints = 40;
  /* rest of initialization */
}
```

If there is no common superset constructor, you can still use "this" to do the common work. You may need to use a special private constructor:

```
private Zombie(boolean special) {
  damagePoints = 40;
}

public Zombie() {
  this(true);
  /* Rest of the constructor */
}
```